# C++ split string using a list of words as separators

Tags: c++, regex, string, std

I would like to split a string like this one

```
“this1245is@g$0,therhsuidthing345”
```

using a list of words like the one bellow

```
{“this”, “is”, “the”, “thing”}
```

into this list

```
{“this”, “1245”, “is”, “@g$0,”, “the”,  “rhsuid”, “thing”, “345”}
// ^--------------^---------------^------------------^-- these were the delimiters
```

The delimiters are allowed to appear more than once in the string to split, and it can be done using regular expressions

The precedence is in the order in which the delimiters appear in the array

The platform I'm developing for has no support for the Boost library

**Update**

This is what I have for the moment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    std::string s ("this1245is@g$0,therhsuidthing345");
    std::string delimiters[] = {"this", "is", "the", "thing"};

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        std::string delimiter =  "(" + delimiters[i] + ")(.*)";
        std::regex e (delimiter);   // matches words beginning by the i-th delimiter

        // default constructor = end-of-sequence:
        std::sregex_token_iterator rend;

        std::cout << "1st and 2nd submatches:";
        int submatches[] = { 1, 2 };
        std::sregex_token_iterator c ( s.begin(), s.end(), e, submatches );
        while (c!=rend) std::cout << " [" << *c++ << "]";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1st and 2nd submatches:[this][x1245fisA@g$0,therhsuidthing345]
1st and 2nd submatches:[is][x1245fisA@g$0,therhsuidthing345]
1st and 2nd submatches:[the][rhsuidthing345]
1st and 2nd submatches:[thing][345]
```

I think I need to make some recursive thing to call on each iteration

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Where did you get stuck? What have you tried searching and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Are you going by first word found, largest collection of letters identifing a word or something else?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I quite don't understand what you mean, but can you please take a look at the updated question, maybe there is what you are asking for

Comment: The match on "is" takes precedence on matching on "this". What behavior do you actually want?

Comment: @jxh yes, the precedence would be in the order that the delimiters appears in the array of delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to perform the precedence requirement. This seems to work on the given input:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse (std::string s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    std::regex re("\(this|is|the|thing).*");
    std::string word;

    auto i = s.begin();
    while (i != s.end()) {
        std::match_results<std::string::iterator> m;
        if (std::regex_match(i, s.end(), m, re)) {
            if (!word.empty()) {
                out.push_back(word);
                word.clear();
            }
            out.push_back(std::string(m[1].first, m[1].second));
            i += out.back().size();
        } else {
            word += *i++;
        }
    }
    if (!word.empty()) {
        out.push_back(word);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, "this" takes precedence over "is" because it appears first in the regular expression

Answer (score 3):

Build the expression you want for matches only (`re`), then pass in `{-1, 0}` to your `std::sregex_token_iterator` to return all non-matches (`-1`) and matches (`0`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
   std::string s("this1245is@g$0,therhsuidthing345");
   std::regex re("(this|is|the|thing)");

   std::sregex_token_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), re, { -1, 0 });
   std::sregex_token_iterator end;

   while (iter != end) {
      //Works in vc13, clang requires you increment separately,
      //haven't gone into implementation to see if/how ssub_match is affected.
      //Workaround: increment separately.
      //std::cout << "[" << *iter++ << "] ";
        std::cout << "[" << *iter << "] ";
        ++iter;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the output I get using your code: `[] [is] [1245] [the] [@g$0,] [thing] [rhsuid] [] [345]`, but that is not the right output, does is change the order of the tokens?

Comment: It should return iterators that alternate between non-matches and matches (the order you pass the submatch `{-1, 0}` matters).  Delimiting your string with the words in nonmatched then matched order should be `[] [this] [1245] [is] [@g$0,] [the] [rhsuid] [thing] [345]`.

Comment: Is there a way to drop the empty tokens? those with `[]`

Comment: If you only care about matched and unmatched pairs, you can always just increase the iterator once and iterate until the end, such as:

`std::vector<std::string> tokens(iter+1, end);`

Comment: This is pretty neat. I used to operate with the old C-style regex, where you use that the width of strings in e.g. snprintf can be dynamic.. This is so much nicer - unfortunately, this feature is not implemented in GCC 4.7.2 (or am I missing something?)

Comment: 4.8.2 had partial STL Regex support if I remember correctly. 4.9 appears to have full support according to their [changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html).

Comment: Really this is a much nicer solution, unfortunately it seems compiler dependant, I'm getting some weird things with clang in Xcode 5.

Comment: Just loaded up my macbook with clang (llvm 3.4) and I believe you are seeing a bug with the postfix increment of `sregex_token_iterator`.  Prefix incrementing and container range construction both are working correctly and alternately iterate over the returned sets of submatches.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> strs; 
boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_space());
```

Comment: Boost can't be used, sorry that I didn't mention this condition in the original post